# Failed to execute 'createObjectStore' on 'IDBDatabase'

Tags: indexeddb, javascript

Привет. прошу помощи в решении проблем :

```
var idb = window.indexedDB ||    // Use the standard DB API
    window.mozIndexedDB ||             // Or Firefox's early version of it
    window.webkitIndexedDB;            // Or Chrome's early version
// Firefox does not prefix these two:
var IDBTransaction = window.IDBTransaction || window.webkitIDBTransaction;
var IDBKeyRange = window.IDBKeyRange || window.webkitIDBKeyRange;  /*Що це за ?*/

var dbName='nameDb';

var idbRequest=idb.open(dbName,'4.67' /*,dbDescription  */);

//dbName – имя базы данных, dbDescription – её описание (опционально)
//И навесим на него обработчики
idbRequest.onsuccess=function (e) {
    debugger

    var db=e.target.result;

    //var transaction=e.target.transaction;

     if (!db.objectStoreNames.contains('chat')){
  //объект для хранения записей из чата
  co=db.createObjectStore('chat',{'id':100});

 };
 if (!db.objectStoreNames.contains('iam')){
  //объект для хранения настроек пользователя
  co1=db.createObjectStore('iam');
 };

/*  Deprecated;
        request = browserDatabase._db.setVersion('5');

       request.onerror = function(e) { alert("error") };

        request.onblocked = function(e){}

        request.onsuccess = function(e)
        {
              //действия над объектами данных
          //  browserDatabase._db.createObjectStore(browserDatabase._storeName, {autoIncrement: true});
        }
    */

};
idbRequest.onerror=function (e) {
    debugger
};
```

получаю ошибку **Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to execute 'createObjectStore' on 'IDBDatabase': The database is not running a version change transaction. index.html:37 idbRequest.onsuccess**

в одной с статей написано что *Создавать хранилища объектов можно только во время транзакции SetVersion. Мы еще не рассматривали метод setVersion, но он очень важен, поскольку является единственным средством создания хранилищ объектов и индексов в коде.*

Но у меня нету метода setVersion (также читал что он Depracated)